# Before today, I (thought/was thinking/used to think)

Tags: tense, coordination

How can one talk about their thoughts or what they used to believe before another action in the past.

If that thought or belief is general, then I guess we can use used to.

Assume these examples (the first one is more general than the second one):

> 1- Before today, I (**believed** / **was believing** / **used to believe**) that the moon (**is** / **was**) a star.
>
> 2- I (**thought** / **was thinking** / **used to think**) she (**was** / **is**) still in the office before I called her.

Which ones in the parentheses are correct?

Comment: By the way, I'm aware of this thread http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/difference-between-was-thinking-thought-have-thought-had-thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Before today, I **believed** that the moon **was** a star.

You could also say:

> 1) I **used to believe** that the moon **was** a star.

Using *before today* with *used to believe* is redundant and at least to me sounds odd.

You would use *was* because we are talking about a past belief, not what the moon actually is.

> 2) I **thought/was thinking** she **was** still in the office before I called her.

Either *thought/was thinking* could be used depending on context. But not *used to think* because that indicates multiple instances, while *called* seems to be a singular event.

And use *was* to match the past tense.