# Why is 'I was just thinking' preferred over 'I have just thought'?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Both constructions seem capable of expressing 'I thought something very recently'. Why is the former preferred over the latter?

Comment: Because thinking is an action that takes time, and is thus suited to be used with a continuous present. "I was just thinking" means that you were in the continuous process of thinking about it.
See: [Difference between (was thinking / thought / have thought / had thought](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/difference-between-was-thinking-thought-have-thought-had-thought?rq=1)

Comment: "just thought" usually refers to a completed thought, for example "I just thought you were going to the store."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because thinking is an action that takes time, and is thus suited to be used with a continuous present. "I was just thinking" means that you were in the continuous process of thinking about it. See: [Difference between (was thinking / thought / have thought / had thought)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/difference-between-was-thinking-thought-have-thought-had-thought?rq=1)